# understanding the algorithm of the genetic algorithm on the example of the task

Tags: c#, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

> You work with a company for the delivery of goods, which daily uses a
>   toll road. Paying for travel at 10 payment points along along. The
>   drivers of the company need to overcome the whole path by paying a
>   commission for each of the points. The difficulty is that according to
>   the rules, the commission can pay only one single coin. In the event
>   that it is higher than the fare, the driver does not receive the
>   change and is worried. If, on the contrary, the coin does not fully
>   cover the fare, then your company has a debt. At the same time, the
>   fare at each of the points is absolutely arbitrary at the end of the
>   day, and can vary in the range from 1 to 10 cents inclusive. It is
>   also known that several payment points can expose the same fare, and
>   the total amount of travel through all points will always be more than
>   55 kopecks. Each driver at the beginning of the journey is given 10
>   coins, one coin of dignity per penny, one coin worth two kopecks, one
>   - three, and so on, up to ten kopecks inclusive). Using the genetic algorithm, you need to find a travel payment strategy in which the
>   driver's debt at the end of the journey will be minimal. The algorithm
>   will be held at the beginning of each day, and use data on new, newly
>   established, commission sizes at payment points to obtain a new
>   strategy for drivers.
>
> Incoming parameters: An array of ten arbitrary numbers from 1 to 10,
>   representing the size of commissions on each of the items. The numbers
>   in the array can be repeated, and their sum will always be greater
>   than 55.
>
> Output: An array of ten numbers representing the merits of coins
>   arranged in the order optimal for payments at each of the points (so
>   that the company's debt after all payments was minimal).

Was involved in writing so I forgot about one of the conditions, this is not finding a free ride but finding the optimal because free ride

> The numbers in the array can be repeated, and their sum will always be
>   greater than 55.

is impossible. I think I'm on the right track but the selection needs to be changed, like the generation of drivers. Here is my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication16
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
        Random rand = new Random();
        bool weNeedContinue = true;          
        int[] propuski1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] bestWay = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] propuski = PropuskiPrice(propuski1);
        int[] car = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        GenerateCar(car,bestWay);
        int[] moneyChange = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };                    
        while(weNeedContinue == true)
        {
            GettingBest(moneyChange, car, propuski, bestWay);
            GenerateCar(car, bestWay);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("luchshii put " + bestWay[i]);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" car " + car[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(" propusk " + propuski[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            ContinueOrNot(bestWay, weNeedContinue);
        }          

    }

    public static int[] PropuskiPrice(int[] a)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int summa = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rand.Next(10) + 1;
            summa += a[i];
            if (i == 9 && summa <= 55)
            {
                PropuskiPrice(a);
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////Создаем водителя/////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    public static int[]  GenerateCar(int[] a,int[] c)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if(c[i] != 0)
            {
                a[i] = c[i];
                continue;
            }
            int b = rand.Next(1, 11);
            if (!a.Contains(b))
            {
                a[i] = b;
            }
            else
                i--;
            if(i == a.Length - 1 )
            {

            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////INIT////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    static void GettingBest(int[] change,int[] car,int[] propuski,int[] bestOne)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
            {
                change[i] = car[i] - propuski[i];
                if (change[i] == 0)
                {
                    bestOne[i] = car[i];
                /*Console.WriteLine("Карман" + car[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("Цена" + propuski[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("Лучший путь"+ bestOne[i]);*/
                }
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (change[i] == -1 || change[i] == 1)
            {
                bestOne[i] = car[i];
                Console.WriteLine(bestOne[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (change[i] == -2 || change[i] == 2)
            {
                bestOne[i] = car[i];
                Console.WriteLine(bestOne[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (change[i] == -3 || change[i] == 3)
            {
                bestOne[i] = car[i];
                Console.WriteLine(bestOne[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////Prodoljat ili net////////////////////////////// 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////


    static void ContinueOrNot(int[] bestWay,bool weNeedContinue)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (bestWay[i] != 0)
            {
                weNeedContinue = true;
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                weNeedContinue = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
    }
```

**The PropuskiPrice (int [] a)** method itself is the generation of prices for skips when the program is launched.

**GenerateCar (int [] a, int [] c)** - creating the driver, this is actually what I would like to change, the method does not meet the requirements of full selection, it will only pick up values ​​that are more or less suitable.

**GettingBest (int [] change, int [] car, int [] propuski, int [] bestOne)** - also does not satisfy the requirements of full selection, it only selects values ​​that are more or less suitable.

**ContinueOrNot (int [] bestWay, bool weNeedContinue)** - check for continuation.

In general, I'm in a dead end.If someone has ideas how to dazzle what I need will be very grateful.

P.S. (**I do not ask to write everything for me**, I ask only to look at this and tell where in the root to change the logic that would have turned out what you need)

P.S.s. (I certainly will not mind if someone specifically says that to remake (= 
  )

P.S.s.s. (I beg you not to evaluate the "quality of code", I literally study for 2 weeks, if someone tells me how to optimize the code and look at this example I will be very grateful!)

Comment: The recursive method PropuskiPrice needs to be fixed.  It needs to reference the arrays : propuski1, bestWay, and  propuski.  See my combination code at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446523/online-word-combination-calculator-for-different-combinations-of-words/51446894#comment89864579_51446894

Comment: Ty! I have one more var of this algorithm, chek it if u can - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/858668/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE


Now problem that piece of code just didnt work.

Comment: You still have the same issue with PropuskiPrice() method.  It doesn't work properly.